# Canvas.clearRect is not a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

Trying to add a bit of canvas animation in my Portfolio website, I'm copying a simple animation from another project but I'm having an issue. .clearRect isn't a function in React :(

```
 animate = c => {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    c.fillStyle = "white";

    c.fillRect(this.state.positionX, this.state.positionY, 20, 20);

    this.state.positionX += this.state.xSpeed;
    this.state.positionY += this.state.ySpeed;

    if (this.state.positionX === 780) this.setState({ xSpeed: -2 });
    if (this.state.positionX === 0) this.setState({ xSpeed: 2 });
    if (this.state.positionY === 0) this.setState({ ySpeed: 2 });
    if (this.state.positionY === 580) this.setState({ xSpeed: -2 });
  };
```

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canv");
    const c = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.animate(c);
  }
```

Comment: in `componentDidMount` what do you see in the console when you add `console.log(c)`?

Comment: @AlexWayne I get back  ```       CanvasRenderingContext2Dcanvas: <canvas      id="canv" width="800" height="600"> ``` and then all the other info like fillStyle, font, etc.

Comment: I can simply draw just fine with it, its just the .clearRect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing your drawing context when `animate` is called from `requestAnimationFrame`. It works the first time through, because you call `this.animate(c);` and pass `c` right into `animate`.

You need to create a function that captures `c` and passes it to the next frame.

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animate(c));
```